# How to highlight some attribute value of some XML tags in Emacs Web mode?

Tags: xml, emacs, highlight, major-mode

I'm using the excellent web-mode in Emacs for editing XML files.

I would like to highlight some attribute value from specific tags. How is that possible?

For example, in the following file:

```
<panel type="console" ds="DS_CONSOLE_EQ" layout="mainLayout">
    <title>Filter</title>
    <field table="eq" id="BL_ID"/>
    <field table="eq" name="fl_id"/>
    <field table="eq" name="rm_id"/>
    <field table="eq" name="eq_id"/>
</panel>
```

I would like to highlight the **value** from every

- `ds` attribute from the `panel` tag, and
- `id` attribute from the `field` tag.

In this case, `ds_console_eq` and `bl_id` would be highlighted (with 2 different faces). I've put them in caps letter to show the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using font-lock-mode just change font-lock-type-face and font-lock-keyword-face to whatever faces you want

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
   '(("\\<ds_console_eq\\>" . font-lock-type-face)
     ("\\<bl_id\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the values highlighted are just examples here. The question is to highlight the value of the properties `ds` and `id`, whatever they are.

Comment: @user3341592 Just change `\\<ds_console_eq\\>` and `\\<bl_id\\>` to whatever you want in the code

Comment: No, the strings aren't static: it's whatever is enclosed in the double quotes following the 2 given attributes; so, that can't be modified like that in the code. The code must be able to find those strings.